# PHP query get results from Database based on first letter of username

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code that im working with:

```
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT DISTINCT number, customerNumber FROM countries, customers WHERE admin.username= '$usernameDB'" );
```

The `admin.username` is the name of the user which is currently logged in the system and the `number` and `customerNumber` are numbers that this `admin.username` has created and modified so i generate a table based on the `$result` values. What i need is to get all the `number` and `customerNumber` that a certain `admin.name` has created/modified but based on the first letter of this specific `admin.username`. I was thinking something to try something like

```
WHERE admin.username LIKE '$usernameDB%'
```

but this doesn't work.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use `LIKE`, not `=`.

Comment: `=` is for exact match, `LIKE` is for matching a pattern with wildcards.

Comment: You also need a joining condition between the tables, otherwise you'll get a full cross product.

Comment: @Barnar i used LIKE in the code but missspelled it here i'm sorry for that. I'm not sure that i need to join the tables because the query that i get is correct i just need to fix the php query to get the results that  i want.

Comment: There's no `admin` table in your `FROM` clause, you can't access `admin.username`.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

SELECT author FROM lyrics WHERE author LIKE 'B%';

Comment: This is a static solution meaning i will get only the results from authors with name that starts with `B` and that is not what im looking. I need results based on the `admin.username`  but the username is always different i mean there are different users that use this system and they don't have the same names....

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not clear nor proper relations between tables

---

Try...

```
WHERE admin.username LIKE '".$usernameDB."%'"
```